# withdrawn as I spotted my error

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

DOH - BRAIN FAILURE - I JUST SPOTTED MY STUPID ERROR - SORRY ALL.
NOT SURE HOW I CAN WITHDRAW THE QUESTION? - SO I'VE JUST DELETED THE CONTENT!

Comment: `$sql = "DELETE FROM TEMPLOAD WHERE STOCK IN ";`  this is not gonna delete anything because you never run this query

Comment: Your SQL is in `$sql`, but you're running `$import`?

Comment: you should also use `mysqli_multi_query()`

Comment: you should be able to delete the question quite easily. Check the help centre if you're not sure what to do.